# Connecting to Apache files remotely when using different port

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

So I'm working on a class project involving setting up a LAMP server using the instructions [here](https://peppe8o.com/lamp-server-on-raspberry-pi/). I was able to get everything setup and running fine... on my LAN. But nothing outside my LAN could connect to the sites. I did some research, and, based on what I found, changed the port Apache was listening to. Now devices could connect to the front page of my Apache server by adding the port to the end of the URI.

Unfortunately, the `test.php` page and the `phpmyadmin` page still can't be accessed remotely. I'm not sure what to do to correct the issue.

Comment: The IP address from your server should be accessible from the outside. Make sure that you have configured routing properly and tested it using `ping` command

Comment: I can ping the server. The only problem I'm having is accessing anything except the root page (I can get to example.com:XXXX, but not example.com/file.php:XXXX).

Comment: You need to request example.com:xxxx/file.php

Comment: Razenstein is right. It should be `IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER/file.php`. Also make sure the firewall rules allow that port.